# Can I plug my SD card from Pi 3 into a Pi 4?

Tags: update, pi-4

If I upgrade the OS to buster on an OS disk (SD card or USB stick) on my pi 3, will it work if I boot a pi 4 off that?

Comment: it should - it won't hurt to try

Comment: The Foundation advice is to do a new installation - NOT attempt upgrade.

Comment: @milliways where's the fun in that? But my question is not about the merits of upgrading, but if the same disk used for a pi3 will work on a pi3, assuming it's running Buster.

Comment: make a backup and try - I went from jessie->stretch without issue on my pi, and that was a far bigger change than stretch->buster - except for the MUCH larger boot partition requirement of course - but even that can, with some magic, be handled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done, but requires a bit of work to get the bootloader updated for Raspberry Pi 4. Here's how I did it:

1. Back up your SD card!!! This can go wrong any number of ways. Not my fault if you bork something!
2. Upgrade Raspbian on your Pi 3 to Raspbian Buster.
3. Use [Gparted](https://gparted.org/) on another computer to enlarge the boot partition of the card to 250MB. Make sure you don't move the start position of the boot partition.
4. Put the card back in the Pi 3 and update the bootloader with the command `sudo apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
5. Put the card in your Pi 4 and hope for the best.

Comment: won't work.  `apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-kernel` will auto-remove the /boot/kernel7l.img needed by Raspberry pi 4...

Comment: It worked for me, once my boot partition was enlarged.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Buster from Stretch isn't recommended. Install a new card and copy your old programs & data from the old system.

As long as you get the new kernel and firmware/bootcode for the BCM2711 processor installed on your SDCard it will boot on a RPi4.

If the card has NOOBS then forget it. Updating NOOBS for a new processor is a pain (always has been). It's not impossible, but it's not easy.

Comment: FWIW I upgraded fine from Buster to Stretch on my Pi 3 (with a few hiccups). However, moving the SD card to a Pi 4 failed. What do you mean exactly by the second paragraph? How would we do that precisely?

Comment: I actually think my question is slightly different to this, because the Stretch -> Buster part isn't relevant. I've opened a [new question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/103841).

Comment: You need to ensure that the stuff in the /boot folder in partition #1 (and partition #5 if NOOBS) has the kernel and bootcode for a RPi4. If you don't understand that then you have no choice but to build a fresh new SDCard for your new RPi4.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to at first, instead of booting I was presented with a blank black screen however I was easily able to resolve it and get booted up! Hope this helps.

- Before doing anything, I updated the Pi3 so that it was running Buster.

  1. Download the latest Buster `.img` from RaspberryPi
  2. Remove the sd card from Pi3 and plug in your micro sd so that you can access the files on your computer.
  3. Using windows explorer (on Windows) open the sd card so that you can see the files in `/boot`
  4. Using 7zip or another tool that allows you to view the files in an .img, open the .img you downloaded above.  Expand the 0.fat folder and
  5. Copy (Yes to overwrite when prompted) all the `start4*.elf` and `fixup4*.dat` as well as the `kernel7l.img`

NOTE:  It doesn't hurt to copy all `bcm*_.dtb` files and allow overwriting.  If you are missing the `bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb` then you copy simply copy that one only to your sd card.  Always backup before making changes.

After making those changes, I ejected the sd card, plugged it into my Pi4 and it booted very quickly!